# PHP- How to disable a hyperlink if option not selected?

Tags: javascript, php, twitter-bootstrap

I'm trying to disable the hyperlink if an option is not selected. The problem is that the this is an existing project in my company and the original coder isn't here anymore. So I cannot find the HTML source. All I have is this array. I tried using javascript like we do in the `<option>` tag, but it doesn't work.

```
array("type"=>"select", "name"=>"agentId", "value"=>getAgentASMOption($partyCode), "title"=>"Select Party" ),

<td class="no-border" align="center">
    <a href="<?php echo SITEURL; ?>/productnew/productnew-details/?id=<?php echo $d['mmID']; ?>&mCatID=<?php echo $_REQUEST["mCatID"];?>  ">
     <label>View</label>
    </a>
</td>



function getAgentASMOption($partyCode=0) {
    global $DB;
    $sel = "";
    $sql ="SELECT DISTINCT(A.partyCode), P.NAME1, P.ORT01 FROM`".$DB->pre."agent_party` AS A LEFT JOIN `".$DB->pre."party_master` AS P ON P.KUNNR=A.partyCode where A.agentCode = '".sprintf('%d',$_COOKIE['PARTYCODE'])."'  ORDER BY P.NAME1 ASC"; 

    $res = $DB->dbRows($sql);
    if($DB->numRows> 0){
        foreach($res as $asm) {
            $sel = "";
            if($asm['partyCode'] == $partyCode) { $sel = "selected"; }
            //$str .= '<option value="'.$asm['partyCode'].'" '.$sel.'>'.$asm['NAME1'].'</option>';
            $str .= '<option value="'.$asm['partyCode'].'" '.$sel.'>'.$asm['NAME1'].' ----- '.$asm['ORT01'].' -----  '.$asm['partyCode'].' </option>';
        }   
    }   
}
```

Rendered HTML:-

```
<select id="agentId" name="agentId" title="Select"></select>

    <option value="">--Select--</option>
    <option value="1002410">(MUMBAI) SANDEEP FABRICS ----- KALBADEVI -----  1002410 </option>
    <option value="1013283">(PALGHAR)BLUE SKIES FASHION AVENUE ----- PALGHAR -----  1013283 </option>
</select>



  $sql = "SELECT NAME1,ORT01 FROM `" . $DB->pre . "party_master`WHERE `KUNNR`= '" .$_SESSION['party_Code']. "'";
           $res = $DB->dbRow($sql);
```

Comment: Please post a [mcve] using the `<>` snippet editor

Comment: The question is not clear about what exactly is your requirement.

Comment: your code is not supporting your question .Please clarify you problem

Comment: Make a `if` statement, store a value into it with: `onclick="return false;"`?

Comment: @HansSolo  checking your code i can say that at-least one value will always selected in any case because there is no option like `<option value="">Select Options</option>`

Comment: @Alive Actually that is written in the array like "title"=>"Select Party "

Comment: your code seems framework . isn't it ?

Comment: Sadly this is not my code. This is an existing project that the company gave me to make some modifications. So I'm not sure if some framework is used in it.

Comment: @HansSolo  can you please show your actual rendered select box html on your browser?

Comment: A screenshot? @AlivetoDie

Comment: No. when you page is opened . open browser developer tool and click on element section. now go to  that select box and then ciopy-paste that html from element section to here in your question.

Comment: @HansSolo  full sect-box html with options.

Comment: @AlivetoDie There are hundreds of options in it. Shall I post it here?

Comment: Just [mcve] - so an example with 3 options

Comment: @HansSolo  no not all but show first 3 options

Comment: Updated. Kindly check.

Comment: @HansSolo  check mplungjan answer:-https://stackoverflow.com/a/44561608/4248328

Answer (score 1):

If you give the link an ID or class, it is safer to select than what I had to do now

NOTE: Links do not have disable property so the code below is using CSS and event preventDefault

Assuming the select has a `<option value="">Select Party</option>`, you can do this:

```js
$(function() {
  $("#agentId").on("change", function() {
    if ($(this).val() == "") {
      $(".proddet").prop("disabled","disabled");
      $(".proddet").addClass("disabled");
    } 
    else {
      $(".proddet").removeProp("disabled");
      $(".proddet").removeClass("disabled");
    }
  }).change(); // in case a "selected" option is already present
  $(".proddet").on("click",function(e) {
    if ($(this).prop("disabled") !== undefined) {
      e.preventDefault();
    }
  })
});
```

```css
a[disabled] { pointer-events:ignore; color:lightgray }
a.disabled { pointer-events:ignore; color:lightgray }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="agentId" name="agentId" title="Select">
<option value="">--Select--</option>
<option value="1002410">(MUMBAI) SANDEEP FABRICS ----- KALBADEVI -----  1002410 </option>
<option value="1013283">(PALGHAR)BLUE SKIES FASHION AVENUE ----- PALGHAR -----  1013283 </option>
</select>

<table>
  <tr>
    <td class="no-border" align="center">
      <a class="proddet"  href="/productnew/productnew-details/?id=<?php echo $d['mmID']; ?>&mCatID=bla">
        <label>View</label>
      </a>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: @HansSolo  DID YOU ADDED JqUERY LIBRARY BEFORE THIS CODE.

Comment: Phew - much harder than I thought

Comment: Guys it's not working. This PHP code is really complex. I'll try to locate the HTML and then try this solution. Thanks a lot for your help. Much appreciated.

Comment: Yes @AlivetoDie The Jquery and Bootstrap files are in a separate file in the project.

Comment: HI guys.. If you're still there, I've updated the question with the sql that is getting the data. Is it possible to disable the hyperlink using the session variable in the query?

Comment: Just place my code in the head of the file after jQuery and it will work. If it does not work, then there are console errors that will show you why not. You cannot disable the link on the server depending on the select state unless you submit each time the select is changed

Comment: The head is in a different file. Will it work from there?

Comment: Also in a script tag elsewhere